# Find Xamarin class name or namespace in android java code

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an android aar which is used in ReactNative and Xamarin android. I need to find the native api is called from which hybrid framework. For ReactNative I used `Class reactClass = Class.forClass("com.facebook.react.ReactActivity")` , if reactClass is not null then it was called from ReactNative. How do I find for Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Do you  try to do like below ?

```
Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(YourClass)).Name
```

Comment: Is this to be added in Xamarin or in native android ? I need to check in native android if the API was called by RN or Xamarin.

Comment: This is called in Xamarin.Android.